# How can I improve my current spreadsheet time formula?

Tags: google-sheets

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(filter(A4:A,A4:A<>""),IF((B4:B>TIMEVALUE("10:00:00"))*(B4:B<TIMEVALUE("17:00:00")),"Yes","Not")))
```

I succeeded at making my time table to show whether it's collected during work time or not. But since I don't work during weekends, I  need it to show whether it's collected during normal weekday or during weekend. (I'm trying to find the average of the general response time for my company's inbound calls)

Can I please get a help on this?

In short, I need to make my last column show:

- For the data collected during workdays whether it was collected between 10:00am ~ 5:00pm (YES, NOT)
- and shows "weekend" for the data that were collected during weekend.

and here's [the sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14X9zYMuU_0tJE43W8lHFO3F_yjA3qnVq1LhGLex1jqo/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use multiple columns.

In one I would determine if the day is a weekend or weekday.

In the other I would determine if it is during work hours. You could even determine if it was before or after work hours.

Then I would use those cells to determine what category they apply to.

Breaking it into stages may allow you to use a more readable or  less complex formula. The answers in those extra columns could also help in creating a pivot table.